# InfoPath form data for an item(multiple-selection list box) not being saved in From Library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath

InfoPath form data for an item(multiple-selection list box) not being saved in Form Library in SharePoint 2013.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the properties for the control, and see if it updates correctly (when anything changes).